# zeroes of homogeneous analytic $p$-adic functions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to understand Lemme 2.1 page 3 of [this paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/vincent.pilloni/formes_surc.pdf) by Pilloni.

What is says (I think) is that if you have, for a a positive real number $w$,  an analytic function 
$$
f : \mathbf{Z}_p^\times(1+p^w \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{C}_p}) \longrightarrow \mathbf{C}_p^\times
$$
which is homogenous of weight a character : $\kappa : \mathbf{Z}_p^\times \to \mathbf{C}_p^\times$ under $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$ i.e.
$$
 f(\lambda x) = \kappa(\lambda)f(x)
$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathbf{Z}_p^\times$, such that $f$ is zero on $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$ then $f$ is zero.

Pilloni says that this is a consequence of the Weierstrass Preparation theorem. I know that Weierstrass preparation implies that if an analytic function has an infinite number of roots of **positive** valuation then $f$ is zero. But here our zeroes are invertible (i.e. they have $0$ valuation).

I think maybe it should be a consequence of homogeneity or maybe we should use log/exp but I haven't been able to write down the details.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: Thanks but I think it is very elementary and easy. If nobody has an idea I will follow your suggestion though.

Comment: This is saying that $f$ vanishes on $\left(1 + p\mathbb Z_p\right) \cap \left(1+p^w\cal O_{\mathbb C_p}\right)$ - do you agree?

Comment: My point being - if I understood correctly -  that one uses Weierstrass on $g(z)= f(1+z)$.

Comment: Well I can't see why this doesn't work so ... i guess it does :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For no other reason than to take this question off of the unanswered queue...

As in the comment section above:

By hypothesis, the analytic function $f$ vanishes on $\mathbb Z_p^*$.

Since $\mathbb Z_p^* \supset 1 +p\mathbb Z_p $, $f$ vanishes on the infinite set $\left(1 + p\mathbb Z_p\right) \cap \left(1+p^w\cal O_{\mathbb C_p}\right)$. One can now use the $p$-adic Weierstrass preparation theorem to conclude that $g(z) = f(1+z)$ vanishes on $p^w\cal O_{\mathbb C_p}$.

Therefore, by $\mathbb Z_p^*$-homogeneity, $f$ is identically zero on $\mathbb Z_p^*\left(1+p^w\cal O_{\mathbb C_p}\right) $.

Comment: This looks right to me. The key is certainly to look at a disk (ball?) centered at $1$ rather than at zero.

Comment: Thanks again. I can't upvote yet for reputation reasons.